# How to read data from SQLite database on Eclipse

Tags: database, eclipse, sqlite

I'm using a static database that I created with SQLite Database Browser. I put it in my assets folder and built a code to copy the database to a database variable (Does that make sense?) so I could read information from it. Problem is I don't know how - mostly the SQL queries involved - and what are your suggested methods do to that? In other words, what methods should I add to my Database Handler class (Or data adapter?) in order to present the data in a list view, for example.

Thank you for all your help.

Comment: This is shown in every tutorial. What specific problem do you have?

Comment: Mainly me being unable to found a decent tutorial for my needs. It's either examples here on Stack Overflow that are different than what I'm looking for (By purpose, so obviously their code and usage is way different) or just obscure tutorials here and there. Would you mind linking me to a decent one? I'd be really greatful.
Edit: You seem to have great knowledge of SQL. Would you mind recommending the common methods' name to put inside these Handler classes for future purposes? Extraction of information and such

Comment: Moreover, how would you suggest I should make this as efficient as possible? Is it smart to check each inital run if the copy of my DB exists and then display the data directly or have it set up each run? Maybe a different approach?

Answer (score 0):

Read the [Android database documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#db).

Copying your database from the assets folder is typically done in the `onCreate` and/or `onUpgrade` functions of your `SQLiteOpenHelper`-derived class.

This tutorial covers the basics:
[Using the SQLite Database with ListView](http://kahdev.wordpress.com/2010/09/27/android-using-the-sqlite-database-with-listview/)

As for naming things: use whatever names make sense in your application.